# How I must to use "setValidator"

Tags: qt

I wrote QIntValidator:

```
validator = new QIntValidator(-30,+30,this);
ui->Value_TavRotante_Calib->setValidator(validator);
```

but It works only for `numbers<-30` and it doesn't work for `numbers>30`

Comment: cannot reproduce this... qt version please?

Comment: Maybe try using integer variables, like: `int min=-30; int max=30;` and pass those into the QIntValidator constructor.  Or, looking at the documentation, a more obscure thing may be the locale that you have set misinterprets the characters you are entering in the interface.

Comment: "_It works only for_" Hmm... what do you mean by _work_ here? Validators will only _strictly_ validate when editing is finished (e.g. lost focus or when return is pressed).

Comment: Some other features can easily interfere with validators, when used together. Could you post what is `Value_TavRotante_Calib`, what settings you have set on it, and if any other code touches it?